# Changing the File extension from "Demo.xlsx" to "Demo.pdf" how does it covert the file from doc to pdf?

Tags: excel, pdf, ms-word

In work place everyday we used different type of documents to hold data. For example, DOC, XLSX, PDF files. And sometime we use software (like adobe reader) excel to PDF converter.

As far i know another way to convert a document from excel to pdf is changing the document type from the SaveAs option (correct me if i am wrong) or changing the file extension.

My question is when we change the Document type from save as option does it change the code behind the file?

Another silly question is if we can convert the file by changing extension why we are paying for 3rd party software?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every document type has its format. So behind the screen, every type has its style. For example, XLSX format is a combination of XML and zip compression. PDF is a rich document representation format created by Adobe uses PostScript.
When you save a document as XLSX, the document will be saved as its standards. The saving method will be changed. As an answer to your first question, Yes the coding(method) will be changed when saving.

For the second question, the changing file format is not always an easy task. You need to change the encoding of the file when performing the conversion. When you change the extension you do not apply any conversion operation. You say your computer "This is an ... file.". But the encoding of the file is still unchanged.